# Rails 4 & Ruby 1.9 error generating mongoid:config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a ruby on rails app which can be hosted on Openshift, but i encounter the following error when i try to use the **rails g mongoid:config** command through terminal. I've tried everything i found on stackoverflow but the error still persists! what am i doing wrong?

here is the error:

```
/home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/themis/rails4/config/application.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_job/railtie (LoadError)
    from /home/themis/rails4/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `require'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:82:in `preload'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/themis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

and my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'  
gem 'less-rails' 
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem "rspec"
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an ActiveSupport bug (thus a Rails bug).

Line 282 at `activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb` is

```
def parse(str, now=now)
  # ...
end
```

And line 308 of the same file is

```
def now
  # ...
end
```

The problem is at the default param `now=now`, which ruby struggles to understand whether the latter `now` is a method call or is just a local variable (the param itself).

If you modify the `now=now` to `now=now()`, then all is fine.

This bug is fixed in Rails 4.0.6.

Comment: thanks, but i cant locate these files! it seems that this location doesn't exist

Comment: It's at `/home/themis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb`